# Create an item in two different table with auto-increment C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvvm, linq

First of all, let me apologize because I know my question will be very confusing since my English is pretty bad.

I am working on a project for a company, mainly create a system to take care for their good, using MVVM C#

My MS SQL database looks like this

[image]

So I have auto-increment for both Bike-id and Contact-id. Each time I want to retrieve database from 3 tables, I have to make a join with Linq then get data using webservice, pretty complicated since I can use Lambda for toffee. It works but it messed up.

Furthermore, it is getting more complicated when I want to create bikes from a Contact, I dont want to tell people "hey each time you create a bike, you have to give me a ContactId". Im currently using .Max() or .First() to get a most recent ID, but then it is not flexible. How could I implement that when people click on a List of Contact, if they want to use a contact for creating a new bike, they can just click on a button, the system will know they have chosen that ContactId?

Also, when people create a new bike, I will let them go to the page with full of text box to fill out, of course there could be a new ContactId with a new items, but they are 2 different tables, how do I let it know that I am creating an Item for this ContactId.

Again, Im sorry to confuse you guys since my question it is very unpercisely. But please help me out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple of comments that might help:

> I have to make a join with Linq

This sounds expensive - are you really pulling all records from all 3 tables into your program just so you can do a join?  It would be much better to do that directly in SQL:

```
SELECT b.brand
    ,c.NAME
    ,p.city
FROM bikes b
JOIN Contact c ON b.ownerID = c.ownerID
JOIN Postcode p ON c.postCode = p.postCode
WHERE c.ownerID = @ownerID
```

If I were to create a Bike record, I would definitely say "hey, you have to tell me the ownerID".  Of course, in my program I would create a drop down list with the name of the owner shown to the user and the ownerID as the value returned.

If you were using HTML, it might look something like

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>Bob Smith</option>
    <option value='2'>John Doe</option>
</select>
```

One final note - it is a very common problem to want to create a record then immediately get the primary key.  In Sql Server you can do that with code like:

```
int newContactID = -1;
string name = "bob";
string phoneNo = "555-1212";
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string sql = @"
INSERT INTO Contact (
    NAME
    ,phoneNo
    ,...
    )
VALUES (
    @name
    ,@phoneNo...
    );

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phoneNo", phoneNo));

        newContactID = Int32.Parse((cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Using LINQ to Objects would be expensive. Using LINQ to Entities or something similar wouldn't (since it translates the query into SQL).

Comment: Really appreciated, Dan. Your answer leads me to an idea of creating Views for my tables, I will just try it out tonight.

In regard to invoking store procedures in C#, since I am working with Windows store 8.1, I couldn't use System.Data.Common by any chance. I think I should move to WPF for more flexibility.